# How to pass a variable to s:text?

Tags: struts2, struts

First things first, I'm not a seasoned Struts user. Here is my struts code:

```
<s:set var="foo" value="BAR">

<s:text name="key.for.foo">
    <s:param><s:property value="foo" /></s:param>
</s:text>
```

Here is the properties file containing the `key.for.foo` text value:

```
key.for.foo=blah blah {0}
```

I expect the text below:

```
blah blah BAR
```

but I get

```
blah blah
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
<s:text name="key.for.foo"><s:param value="#foo"/></s:text>
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `<s:set />` vars is covered in the [tag documentation's example](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/set-tag.html):

```
 <s:set var="personName" value="person.name"/>
 Hello, <s:property value="#personName"/>
```

Nutshell is that the [Value Stack](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl.html) has multiple ways of looking things up: stuff pushed onto the stack (e.g., the action itself, `<s:push />` properties), stuff in the servlet context (e.g., session and request attributes/properties), and named objects (e.g., `<s:set />` objects, `<s:iterator />` status value).